# 2013 Image Renditions, no edit rendition option

Tags: 2013, image

I've enabled the blob cache and set up some renditions. I can call these fine by passing in the width and height as parameters to an image.

However I need to edit the renditions as the default settings crop too much - but there is no Edit Renditions menu item in any Asset Library?

Anyone have any ideas? Running on premise with the March PU.

Answer (score 3):

You should have an edit link in the image rendition settings. If not, try using the direct link, and see what result you get.

```
/_layouts/15/NewImageRenditionSettings.aspx?Id=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have publishing features enabled on the site collection?

For image renditions to work you need to have three things done:

- A publishing site collection (or at least the publishing features enabled)
- A configured BLOB cache
- An Asset Library (recommended)

See [SharePoint 2013 Design Manager image renditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720398.aspx) for further reference.

You can also use Picture Libraries, but they're missing the `Edit Renditions` link under the ellipsis (`...`). So instead you need to select your image, which should make the Design tab appear in the ribbon, then under the Design tab click Edit Renditions.